# Is it a noun or a verb?

Tags: grammar

"Will Mr. Collins be affected by the previous news on stocks INCREASE?"

Is increase a verb or a noun in this sentence? thank you very much

Comment: It's a "syntactically awkward" example of *journalese* ("cut-down" syntax as used in newspapers, etc.). It could be more clearly expressed as *...previous news on **the increase** in stocks* - but even that version is just "shorthand" for *...the increase **in the price** of stocks*. Grammatically speaking, ***stocks*** in the example is a *noun adjunct* (a noun used adjectivally to modify the "head" noun ***increase*** that follows).

Comment: oh.. very complicated haha. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Complicated ***and*** awkward. Personally, I don't like ***previous*** (would prefer ***earlier***), or  ***on*** (would prefer ***regarding***).  And if I were writing it I'd have "reversed" those last two nouns anyway, and included the *actual* noun that has "increased" (more properly, "risen") - *Will he be affected by the earlier news regarding rising stock prices?* A few more words, but much easier to parse, even for native speakers.

Comment: I'm not even sure it's grammatically valid even allowing for ellipsis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in comments, the sentence is awkward and complicated. Let us try to simplify

> Mr Collins will be affected by previous news on stocks increase.  (make a statement)
>
> Previous news on stocks increase affects Mr Collins. (present tense and active)

The subject of this sentence is the noun phrase

> "Previous news on stocks increase"

Here it is apparent that "stocks" is an attributive noun, describing the **noun** increase.

But the whole sentence is clumsy and ought to be rephrased:

> Will Mr Collins be affected by the earlier news that stocks had increased in value?
>
> There was news that stocks have increased. Will this affect Mr Collins?